# Fastest news feed APIs targeting high frequency trading?

Tags: programming, high-frequency, news

The Dow Jones elementized news feed API seems to stand out but are there any other machine readable news feeds out there that provide very low latencies that high frequency operations may peruse? I am especially targeting US based economic news releases and US stock related news feeds. I am looking to collocate several of my fx based hft strategies in New York with a very capable fx aggregation platform but also look into US based equities trading based on economic news releases. I am a price taker and have successfully implemented similar solutions on currency pairs in The Asian time zone but look to expand to trade US news releases.

The news feed must originate from one of the major news agencies and the feed must be released 
anywhere between Washington DC and NYC for latency purposes. Generally the news item of economic releases that the department of labor, for example, releases is prepared but quarantined until the dept actually releases their numbers. There have been couple changes enacted recently in order to prevent pre release leakages and I am looking for a solution that optimizes current news flow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are looking for is generally called "machine-readable news". Here are the ones I know about off hand:

- [Dow Jones Elementized News Feed](http://www.dowjones.com/salesandtrading/low-latency-feeds.asp)
- [Thompson Reuters News Feed Direct](http://thomsonreuters.com/products_services/financial/financial_products/a-z/news_feed_direct/)
- [Bloomberg Event-Driven Trading Feed](http://www.bloomberg.com/enterprise/enterprise_products/data_optimization/data_feeds/)
- [NASDAQ OMX Event-Driven Analytics](http://www.nasdaqtrader.com/Trader.aspx?id=EDA)

Good luck getting reliable latency figures from any of those vendors though.

Comment: That is very helpful. Thank you. I generally never rely on hearsay so I may at some point report back after having signed up for trials with those and other vendors and have run extensive tests.

Answer (score 5):

Since you mentioned economic number releases you may be interested in [AlphaFlash](http://www.alphaflash.com/). For trading economic releases they have a fiber that runs into the NY4 data center an supposedly shaves a couple of milliseconds off.

Comment: You are correct. Their POP is at NY4.