# Fed FOMC Target Rate annnouncement machine readable data point

Tags: interest-rates, market-data

Does anyone know if there is a near-realtime machine-readable feed that reflects the FOMC target rate announcement?  The announcement came in today at 2 pm, but I can't find a way to download the revised target rates.

FWIW, 
here is the calendar: http://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/fomccalendars.htm
here is the announcement: http://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/press/monetary/20150917a.htm
Here are the two series (upper/lower bound) on FRED (St. Louis Fed Data engine) but they are updated "next day": https://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/series/DFEDTARU https://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/series/DFEDTARL

I'm hoping for something web-scrapeable from a "federal" source.  The actual latency is not terribly important as long as it's less than a few minutes.

Comment: I noticed there is an RSS feed with the *effective* funds rate, but it does not contain the target rate. http://www.federalreserve.gov/feeds/data/H15_H15.XML

Answer (score 1):

Unsure of any free feeds, but if you have access to bloomberg the tickers for the upper range and lower range are FDTR Index and FDTRFTRL Index respectively. I haven't checked with other providers but I would be very surprised if Reuters did not also provide a similar feed. These tickers update at 2 P.M. however I can't comment on their latency, some discussion of that topic can be found in this  [thread](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/7365/fastest-news-feed-apis-targeting-high-frequency-trading)

Comment: I was hoping for something "web scrape-able" that doesn't require reams of data agreements like BB or Reuters.

Comment: BB & Reuters definitely have feeds. In fact, they were under fire a while ago for releasing it a few microseconds early to some customers. I'd suggest just continuously scrape the Fed's website. It is always posted very timely. After all, this is one of the most important govt releases of any kind.